# Prahlada ruled kingdom being a jivan muktha

Tags: scripture, moksha, yoga-vashishtha, prahlada

Yoga Vasistha contains the story of Prahlada in detail. It is present in [Upasama khanda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118247.html).

The important point needed for this question is that Prahlada rules his kingdom till the end of the kalpa **being a jivan muktha**.

Do any other scripture mentions the fact that Prahlada rules his kingdom being a jivan muktha.